# Images in Applet not showing in web page

Tags: java, jsp, image, applet

I am trying to display a JPEG image and a moving dot on a Java applet which I am using on a web based application. However, when I run the applet it works fine, but when I display the applet from the JSP page, I get the moving dot but not the JPEG image.

Is there a specific folder where the JPEG needs to be?

These are the 2 methods i use for drawing the picture and the moving dot on the screen.

```
public class mapplet extends Applet implements Runnable {

int x_pos = 10;
int y_pos = 100;
int radius = 20;
Image img, img2;
Graphics gr;
URL base;
MediaTracker m;

@Override
public void init() {

        mt = new MediaTracker(this);

        try {
            //getDocumentbase gets the applet path.
           base = getCodeBase();
          img = getImage(base, "picture.jpg");
            m.addImage(img, 1);
            m.waitForAll();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(movement.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }

public void paint (Graphics g) {

 g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
// set color
 g.setColor (Color.red);

// paint a filled colored circle
g.fillOval (x_pos - radius, y_pos - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);

}
```

The code one below is the call from the jsp page

```
<applet archive="mapplet.jar" code="myapplets/mapplet.class" width=350 height=200>
</applet>
```

The jar file and the picture are in the same folder as the jsp page, and there is also a folder containing the contents of the class and image of the applet in the web section of the application. The applet loads fine however the picture doesn't display. I think it's not the code but the location of the picture that is causing a problem.

Thanks

Comment: how do you load image now? show us some code please

Comment: Looks like a path problem. Can you give more details? your applet code and and location of the image on the server would help

Comment: @Suresh:  That was such good advice I was compelled to repeat it in my (almost approaching an) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the image should be in the same folder as the source code. I would recommend to do a folder called images and inside it put all your images and just change "picture.jpg" to "\images\picture.jpg". Check your website directory to see if the image is in the same folder as the source code.

Comment: URLs use a forward slash, not a back slash.  As an aside, the path `/images/picture.jpg` will point to an images directory at the root of the site (no mater where the applet or web page is located).  The path `images/picture.jpg` (without the initial `/`) will point to a directory that is relative to the base URL.

Answer (score 0):

Some comments that might make it more clear for you.

```
//getDocumentbase gets the applet path.
```

No.  `getDocumentBase()` provides the path to the **web page.**  But that is neither here, nor there, since this applet actually calls..

```
base = getCodeBase();
```

..which provides the codebase.  The codebase **defaults** to the directory of the web page, unless a `codebase` parameter is specified in the applet element.  Since the applet element declares no `codebase`, the `base` will be the same URL as the document base.

---

BTW:  In the applet element

```
code="myapplets/mapplet.class"
```

..should be..

```
code="myapplets.mapplet"
```

And since common nomenclature for Java class names is `EachWordUpperCase`, the class name should be changed.

Doe the applet declare?

```
package myapplets;
```

---

BTW (2):

> there is also a folder containing the contents of the class and image of the applet in the web section of the application.

What does that mean?  Please provide complete paths from the root of the server to all resources (e.g. the HTML/JSP, Jar file & image) used.

Answer (score 0):

please check your path ..or to resolve it please put your files inside a folder  and pack it with JAR file.and provide the relative path of image files inside your jar.
Like:
let your applet name is myapp.class in package demoapp
then put your files in dir "images" inside demoapp and provide path relative to this path in all your java code.
dont forget to include image files in jar build.